# How to populate listview in android studio from SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to create a listview in android studio and populate it with data from my database that I've created in SQLite Studio. So I need to display three things in my listview and these three things are in my database: an image, a description, and basically some text. I've been watching some videos and understand that you need to create a database handler class, but this doesn't connect directly to your database in SQLite and also if you do this, then you need to create the table, but my table has already been created and has data in it. I just need to connect to that database, query it, and populate the listview from that, so does anyone know how I can accomplish that?

Comment: This will help: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` needs a `ListAdapter` to access the data model.

The result of SQL query can be returned in a `Cursor`.

So to connect these two concepts, there is a class `CursorAdapter` that takes a `Cursor` and creates a `ListAdapter` that can be used by a `ListView`

Search for some example code with `CursorAdapter`, and you will see how this is accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {  
    Context  context=null;  
    int viewResId;  
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int resource, Cursor cursor) {  
        super(context,cursor);  
        viewResId=resource;  
    }  
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {  

        TextView view =null;  
        LayoutInflater vi = null;  
        vi =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        view =(TextView)vi.inflate(viewResId, parent, false);  
        //v =(TextView)vi.inflate(textViewResourceId,null);  
        Log.i("CursorAdapter","newView"+view);  
        return view;  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {  
        Log.i("hubin","bind"+view);  
        TextView nameView = (TextView) view;  
        // Set the name  
        nameView.setText(cursor  
            .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DISPLAY_NAME")));  
   }  
 }
```